# How to override bang operator(!) for different type of inputs in scala

Tags: scala, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overload bang(!) operator in Scala Actor model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371797/how-to-overload-bang-operator-in-scala-actor-model)

In an Actor model implementation in Scala, can we override the bang(!) operator?
 I need to modify the operation of message passing by overloading this operator?

I need to include logging of the message sent when any actor sends a message to any other actor. 
I started by

```
override def !(msg:Any):Unit =
{
  //logic for writing to logs..
  super.!(msg)
}
```

This works fine. But, i want to differentiate behavior of !, depending upon the messages I am sending.

```
actor_name!(arg1,arg2,arg3)
actor_name1!(arg4, arg5)
```

in the above case, for first ! opertion, i need to perform logging. And for second !, i just want to print on the screen.
How do i differentiate between these two message sending notation in the overriding code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like so ?

```
override def !(msg: Any) {
    msg match {
        case msg@(arg1, arg2, arg3) => /* your logic here... */ ; super ! msg
        case msg@(arg1, arg2) => /* your logic here... */ ; super ! msg
    }
}
```